# How to rewrite code to fix the error(RuntimeError: This event loop is already running. ) websockets + asyncio

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

I have code that performs online recognition. At the moment, it gives an error "RuntimeError: This event loop is already running" on the last line.
Anaconda 2019.10, Python 3.7.4

```
# websockets
async def recognize(url, data):
    async with websockets.connect(url) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(data)
        recognized_text = ""
        recognized_text = await websocket.recv()
        #print(f"< {recognized_text}")
        #print(recognized_text)
        return recognized_text

in_file = open(filename1, "rb")
data = in_file.read()
in_file.close()
print(asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(recognize(url, data)))
```

Here a session is established, and then it is necessary to transfer data for processing and receive recognized text.
I can roughly imagine what a websocket is doing. Establishes a connection to the server, sends data, then waits for a response.
I don’t understand how the asyncio works here.
I read (questions/53248431) that now this does not work because I have a tornado of the version > = 5.0, they suggested lowering the version, but I don’t want to.
How to rewrite it correctly?
Please explain how it works)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because your above program/event is still running because it was not killed.

So in the terminal type the following command:

```
pkill -9 python
```

And then restart the program.

(This works in Linux systems only)

Comment: If this command did not work, then it means you are not using linux Ubuntu.

Comment: In windows open theTask Manager, find the python.exe process that corresponds to your program, and click the "End Process" button.